# Photo gallery not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, pikachoose

I have put together a photo gallery using pikachoose framework. However, the thumbnails on the bottom do not display when viewed in IE 8 and I'm not sure why.

Link to page: http://searchtransparency.net/churchpark/photo-gallery-stackoverflow.html

JavaScript:

```
<!-- Photo Gallery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 880px)" href="slider/styles/styles.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 879px)" href="slider/styles/640.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="slider/styles/480.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="slider/lib/jqueries.js"></script>
<script>
    var gal=jQuery;
    gal.noConflict();
    gal(document).ready(
        function (){
            gal("#lobby").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#apartment-interiors").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#penthouse").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#roofdeck").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#health-club").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#garage").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#galleria").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            gal("#the-views").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
        });
</script>
<script>
function lobby()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.height = 'auto';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.height = '0px';
}
function apartmentinteriors()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.height = 'auto';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.height = '0px';
}
function penthouse()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.height = 'auto';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.height = '0px';
}
function roofdeck()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.height = 'auto';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.height = '0px';
}
function healthclub()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.height = 'auto';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.height = '0px';
}
function garage()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.height = 'auto';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.height = '0px';
}
function galleria()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.height = 'auto';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.height = '0px';
}
function theviews()
{
  document.getElementById('gallery-lobby').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-apartment-interiors').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-penthouse').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-roofdeck').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-health-club').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-garage').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-galleria').style.height = '0px';
  document.getElementById('gallery-the-views').style.height = 'auto';
}
</script>
<!-- Photo Gallery -->
```

HTML:

```
<div class="general-bg">

    <div class="content-bg no-margin-top no-padding-top">

        <div class="content">

            <div id="gallery-lobby" style="height:auto; overflow:hidden;">
                <ul id="lobby">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/lobby/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/lobby/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/lobby/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-apartment-interiors" style="height:0px; overflow:hidden;">
                <ul id="apartment-interiors">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/4.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 4"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/5.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 5"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/6.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 6"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/7.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 7"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/8.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 8"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/9.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 9"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/10.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 10"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/11.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 11"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/apartment-interiors/12.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 12"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-penthouse" style="height:0px; overflow:hidden;">
                <ul id="penthouse">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/penthouse/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/penthouse/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/penthouse/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-roofdeck" style="height:0px; overflow:hidden;">
                <ul id="roofdeck">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/4.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 4"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/5.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 5"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/6.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 6"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/roofdeck/7.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 7"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-health-club" style="height:0px; overflow:hidden;">
                <ul id="health-club">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/health-club/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/health-club/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/health-club/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/health-club/4.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 4"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-garage" style="height:0px; overflow:hidden;">
                <ul id="garage">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/garage/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/garage/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/garage/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/garage/4.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 4"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/garage/5.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 5"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-galleria" style="height:0px; overflow:hidden;">
                <ul id="galleria">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/galleria/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/galleria/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/galleria/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="gallery-the-views" style="height:0px; overflow:hidden;">
                <ul id="the-views">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/the-views/1.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/the-views/2.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/the-views/3.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 3"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/the-views/4.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 4"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/the-views/5.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 5"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery/the-views/6.jpg" width="1000" height="600" alt="Photo 6"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <br>

            <p align="center"><span class="galnav-show"><a onClick="lobby()" href="#">Lobby</a></span><span class="galnav-hide">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="galnav-show"><a onClick="apartmentinteriors()" href="#">Apartment Interiors</a></span><span class="galnav-hide">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="galnav-show"><a onClick="penthouse()" href="#">Penthouse</a></span><span class="galnav-hide">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="galnav-show"><a onClick="roofdeck()" href="#">Roofdeck</a></span><span class="galnav-hide">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="galnav-show"><a onClick="healthclub()" href="#">Health Club</a></span><span class="galnav-hide">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="galnav-show"><a onClick="garage()" href="#">Garage</a></span><span class="galnav-hide">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="galnav-show"><a onClick="galleria()" href="#">Galleria</a></span><span class="galnav-hide">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="galnav-show"><a onClick="theviews()" href="#">The Views</a></span></p>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work properly" isn't a very useful description of the problem.

Comment: I get an error "jCarouse: no width/height set for items. This will cause an infinite loop. Aborting..." from jqueries.js line 16

Comment: @WolfCat Could you replace that line 16 with the indented js here http://jsfiddle.net/WyLnJ/ Once replaced, load the page again and tell us which exact line its showing error for.

Comment: @Rao I've replaced the code, however it seems to be different code from the original and now the slide does not work.

Comment: @DFord - How did you run this error check?

Comment: @Rao - I found that the error is on line 1019

Comment: @WolfCat Could you post the segment of code around line 1019?

Comment: It seems the error is from this script: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.js"></script>. This is the code from line 1019: finally {